# How to: Resize a single div, to fit the container, where there is a tile of like divs

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have a container, full of little divs laid out in tiles. My goal is to click a div, have it resize(animate) to match the container, then on a second click, it will contract back to its original size.

http://jsfiddle.net/taylorRichie/jXd5L/2/

Jquery:

```
$('#bio').click(function(){
    $('.tile').toggleClass("hidden");
    $('#bio').toggleClass("enlarged");
});
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:200px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.tile{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
}

.hidden{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition:all 2300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 2300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 2300ms ease-in-out;
    transition:all 2300ms ease-in-out;
}

#bio{
    background-color:#CCC;
} 

.enlarged{
    min-height:90px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    opacity:1;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:20;
    -webkit-transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

It's sort of working in chrome, but it's not clean, it's not fluid, a lot of shaking, and weirdness.

I would prefer the 'non-clicked' tiles to fade into the back, then fade back in when the original tile is closed.

I'm currently using a mix of CSS3 transitions and jquery for triggers, and toggles.

Thanks!

Richie

++ UPDATE ++

Objective is to click a tile, have it expand to fit the container, then click again to have it return to its original position.

This is just a prototype for testing an interaction, so I may be able to hard code the positions, but when it goes to production (not programmed by me) then it will be dynamic.

I want the transitions to be fluid to give the user a sense of what's happening.

Each div will contain limited information prior to expansion, then the full info once it has completely expanded.

I've been doing so much design work, my dev work is suffering :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your question exactly?  How to make tiles fade?  If there's a smoother transition method?  How do it in other browsers? How to not have all those other blocks shift when you convert the "bio" block from static to absolute position (probably causing some of that "weirdness" you're talking about)? btw, big thanks for making a fiddle! =)

Comment: Will it always be laid out like this? or will this be dynamic.  If there are always going to be 8 tiles, I would suggest making all of them positioned absolute.  Then on click, turn the z-index up and enlarge it and position it absolutely.

Comment: Objective is to click a tile, have it expand to fit the container, then click again to have it return to its original position. This is just a prototype for testing an interaction, so I may be able to hard code the positions, but when it goes to production (not programmed by me) then it will be dynamic. I want the transitions to be fluid to give the user a sense of what's happening. Each div will contain limited information prior to expansion, then the full info once it has completely expanded. I've been doing so much design work, my dev work is suffering :) Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want this happens only on clicking that div?

Comment: Do you want this happens only on click that div? | The method of triggering the expansion doesn't matter to me at this stage, eventually it'll be an icon that activates this interaction. Thanks!

Comment: What you want is the thing that is getting bigger to always go slower than the one getting smaller.  This is why the zoom out looks nice but the shrink down is funky.  If you could change the transition time before the shrink it would look good.  (Or test it with the speeds reversed on the shrink to see what I mean) ... I'm not sure now since I tested it and it did not matter. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think is bit hard to obtain a nice effect with what you have. Maybe you must use `position: absolute;` for your "enlarged" div and then you will get a lot of problems.

In my opinion the best way to animate them is to use jQuery, like i did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jXd5L/7/).

Actually you set `.data()` for current elements where you keep base width/height and then is a small step to play however you want with your animation.

You also can load some [easings](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) to make it more special.

I added `if( t.is(':animated') ) return;` to avoid problems if users try to click while the animation is running

Comment: You rock! That works perfect... I had started with straight jquery, then found another stack where someone used CSS3 transitions, and I thought maybe I'd go that route... Thanks again!

Comment: Follow up question, how come I have to triple click to close after making this edit? http://jsfiddle.net/taylorRichie/C4uVy/1/ Stock in an If statement?